# Split a text by space and capital letter (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to break the text by sentences. There are no dots in this text. But it contains capital letters. I use:

```
 <?php preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*?/Usu',$text,$sentences);
```

But it split the text only by capital letters. So I have such sentences as "S", "M", "S". It is wrong.  I do not need to break such words as SMS. Help please.

Some clarification:

- I try to break the string before each string of one or more capital letters.
- But my real task is more complex. I am trying to format text for readability.
- Example: a piece of vacancy without html tags and line breaks: "Desirable: AWS
  experience Experience with Docker/Kubernetes". I try to get: "Desirable:", "AWS experience" and "Experience with Docker/Kubernetes" (I think I will be able to stick together very short strings after splitting by space and capital letter. Maybe it is a very bad way, of course).

Comment: This sounds pretty difficult with only regexp, I think you should find a better tool.

Comment: Forget about "sentences". You wish to break strings into pieces, the pieces determined by the presence of capital letters. Please edit your question. At the beginning state the specific criteria for determining how the string is to be broken into pieces and then give a few examples for illustration. Do you mean you wish to break the string before each string of one or more capital letters?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I see. Could you suggest a better tool, please?

Comment: `Hello Mr Smith` do you really want that to be 3 sentences?

Comment: I clarified the problem in the description of the question. Thanks @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you you wish to break a string into pieces, where the break points are zero-width positions that immediately precede a capital letter and do not follow a capital letter. If so you could used the following regular expression.

```
(?=(?<![A-Z]|^)[A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7mDFUh/2)

The can be executed as follows:

```
<?php
$result = preg_split("/(?=(?<![A-Z]|^)[A-Z])/", "now is THE time to BE brave"); 
print_r($result);
```

[PHP demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c3b66cc841efef3dcde6d1aa5a9d14d349ba911)

As shown at the link, this returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => now is 
    [1] => THE time to 
    [2] => BE brave
)
```

If the first word of the string were capitalized (`"Now"`), the first element of the string would be `"Now is"` (i.e., not an empty string").

PHP's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  (?<!        # begin a negative lookbehind
    [A-Z]     # match a capital letter
    |         # or
    ^         # match the beginning of the line
  )           # end the negative lookbehind
  [A-Z]       # match a capital letter
)             # end positive lookahead
```

This attempts to match a capital letter in a positive lookahead (`[A-Z]`), but that match fails if the negative lookbehind matches a capital letter preceding it or the capital letter is at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using regex to parse something as complex as natural language. I'd recommend something like `IntlBreakIterator` instead.

```php
$text = "Sentence 1. Sentence 2! Sentence 3? Sentence; number 4...Sentence, 5.";

$it = IntlBreakIterator::createSentenceInstance("en_US");
$it->setText($text);
$parts = $it->getPartsIterator();

foreach ($parts as $point => $sentence) {
    echo "$point => $sentence\n\n\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
0 => Sentence 1. 


1 => Sentence 2! 


2 => Sentence 3? 


3 => Sentence; number 4...


4 => Sentence, 5.
```

The rules for parsing words/sentences can be complex and daunting to implement in a regular expression. This solution is more sane for syntactically correct corpus. However, if the text has no punctuation like you say then there is no sane way to distinguish one sentence from another. Simply attempting to do it by capital letters can yield a lot of false positives because words can be capitalized mid-sentence such as proper nouns and some abbreviations.